# Spring Boot: Executing the Newer version of SQL file each time we rebuild the application

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a `spring-boot` application with `PostgreSQL`. Some of the tables are created using models and other tables have to be created prior to the start of the application or while starting the application. That can be done by running an SQL file while startup.

But DB tend to change over time, we may have to alter some of the tables, add some new tables without disturbing the existing data in the tables, etc.

Is there a way to add new SQL files, and run only the SQL files which was not run in `spring-boot` application each time when we rebuild and rerun? And don't run any of the SQL files while start-up if everything were already executed?

Comment: You can use flyway: https://flywaydb.org/ https://flywaydb.org/documentation/plugins/springboot Example: https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-flyway-database-migration-example/

Comment: @alfcope: This is cool. I was looking for something like this. Please add this as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flyway. It allows you to have versioned sql scripts:

- [flywaydb.org](https://flywaydb.org)
- [flywaydb spring boot plugin](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/plugins/springboot)

  Examples:
- [Spring Boot Database Migrations with Flyway](https://callicoder.com/spring-boot-flyway-database-migration-example)
- [Incrementally changing your db with java and flyway](https://auth0.com/blog/incrementally-changing-your-database-with-java-and-flyway/)

Answer (score 3):

For your scenario liquibase is the best solution. You can merge liquibase on your spring boot application. 
 
Ex: https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-liquibase-example/